# when using BigQuery Client() class getting error TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, google-bigquery

When I am trying to run BigQuery using Client(), getting JSON not serializiable error. Here is my code snippet:

```
client = Client()
query = { "select * from `abc`"}
query_job = client.query(query, location= US)
results = query_job.result().dataframe()
```

Now, when i am trying to it's throwing error. Any help please.

Comment: Welcome! How are you authorizing your client? Are you doing this via a service account json key file?

Comment: on top of @BenP comment, I suggest to check you `python` version and environment setup. There are few guides by Google how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [Bigquery python example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/cloud-client/simple_app.py), you need to pass the `query` value as `STRING` and you're passing a JSON type

For instance:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

query = (
    "SELECT name FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013` "
    'WHERE state = "TX" '
    "LIMIT 100"
)
query_job = client.query(
    query,
    location="US",
) 

for row in query_job:
    assert row[0] == row.name == row["name"]
```

Hope it helps.